# Serialize object through network with Javascript - How to improve it?

Tags: javascript, json, sockets, serialization

I have a class Message which can be serialized when the data goes through the network, I currently use JSON, mostly because I use JSON for everything. (webservice, sockets).

I want to improve the serialization to make it as good as possible, I believe improvments are possible here.

The aim is to make the transport string lighter, especially when used by sockets (video game), because it will be used for *everything*, every response client/server or server/client and even inside the server or client methods, it's the usual way to provide data.

The Message is a complex object that can also contain other object instances, like a MessageLang, which will be responsable to translate a sentence on the client based on a code.

So far it works fine, here are the results:

*Socket server emit with simple string*:

```
verbose: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"user.newAuthenticated","args":["Respond to emitter"]}
```

*Socket server emit with simple message instance*:

```
verbose: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"user.newAuthenticated","args":["{\"m\":\"Respond to all clients\",\"d\":{},\"s\":1,\"t\":\"m\"}"]}
```

*Socket server emit with complex message instance*:

```
verbose: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"user.newAuthenticated","args":["{\"m\":{\"m\":\"__12\",\"a\":{\"field\":\"name\",\"min\":3,\"max\":20}},\"d\":{\"key\":\"fakeKey\"},\"s\":1,\"t\":\"m\"}"]}
```

The complexe message would render the following sentence:

*The min length of name is 3. Max length is 20.* and would contain the `key: "fakeKey"` in `data`. Just to explain how it works.

As you see, the message get bigger and bigger and it is normal, but I would like to know what I can do to make a better serialization here:

- Delete the message itself when there aren't (empty)
- Delete the data when it's empty as well
- Delete the status when it's false (because it's the default value)
- I see a **lot** of `\` in the socket log because it is JSON, I believe that's a problem, because each time I'll add something I'll get extra characters that I do not want. Maybe the JSON isn't a good choice and I should serialize differently, first in JSON like the examples at the top, but then in something else, maybe kind of binary, if it takes less space.

What do you think?

And if it would be a good idea to *encrypt* somehow the message in another format, would the cost of the encryption be worth it? Because encrypt it would take a bit of time as well, so I'm just wondering if it wouldn't just move the issue, like it would take less time to send the message through socket because it would be lighter, but we would use more time to encrypt it. Just wondering.

Comment: I don't see `data` or `status` in the examples.

Comment: There are serialized in respectively `d` and `s`. `m` means `message`.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your message object has two fields (`name` and `args`).

The first stop to reduce the length of the message is to get rid of the (pretty useless) outer object and replace it with an array. So an empty message

```
{"name":"empty","args":[]}
```

would become

```
["empty",[]]
```

or even

```
["empty"]
```

The next thing is that you have a bug in the serialization of the arguments. Instead of sending JSON, you wrap the JSON data in a string. Example: In the authenticated case, you send

```
{"name":"user.newAuthenticated","args":["{\"m\":\"Respond to all clients\",\"d\":{},\"s\":1,\"t\":\"m\"}"]}
```

but you should send

```
{"name":"user.newAuthenticated","args":[{"m":"Respond to all clients","d":{},"s":1,"t":"m"}]}
```

instead. Now the question is whether args is a list of a single object. If it's always a single object, then you could get rid of the `[]` as well. With my suggested change from above, that would give you:

```
["user.newAuthenticated",{"m":"Respond to all clients","d":{},"s":1,"t":"m"}]
```

which is pretty good IMO. If you can make the (de-)serializer handle default values properly, you can reduce this to:

```
["user.newAuthenticated",{"m":"Respond to all clients","s":1,"t":"m"}]
```

(i.e. we can omit the empty `d` property).

Comment: Actually, the message itself as four fields: `m`, `d`, `s` and `t` for `message`, `data`, `status` and `typeMessage`. The `name` you saw is something generated by the socket, as well as the `args`, which actually contains the message itself.

Comment: Also, the `backslashes` are added by the socket itself, not by my own object. It is because *(I think)* it must contain only a string in `args`, since the socket sends only strings. If i do a test in the browser I get the following in the console: `"{"m":{"m":"__12","a":{"field":"name","min":3,"max":20}},"d":{"key":"fakeKey"},"s":1,"t":"m"}"`

Comment: WebSocket itself doesn't add anything to the data which you send. Which framework do you use to communicate via WebSockets?

Comment: Show us the code which you use to get the JSON data which you show in your question.

Comment: A simple `socket.emit('message', new __message('Respond to all clients'))`. If I do a `console.log(new __message('Respond to all clients'))` it displays the JSON without the `backslashes`.

Comment: Why do I see `user.newAuthenticated` in your quesion when you use `socket.emit('message', ...)` to send the data?

Comment: I used `message` because I forgot the example, but I used `socket.emit('user.newAuthenticated', new __message('Respond to all clients'))` actually, sorry for the confusion, answered too fast.

Comment: In that case, it seems that sailsjs encodes the message twice (it creates a JSON string from it and then sends this string instead of creating one JS object that contains the message as field). I don't see an easy way to improve this. Maybe the sailsjs guys made a mistake but maybe the have a good reason for encoding the data twice.

Comment: Hum, okay, I will ask to them then, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

For a MMO, I think a minimum of data must be sent to the client. If a socket is called 2xx/3xx by sec, you must reduce the size of the data sent through the socket as most as possible.

On another hand, it also consummes resource to encrypt the object on the server side to send a minified version of the object... Wouldn't it be better not to reduce it and to send an object not reduced so we don't spent resource to encrypt it?